# Google Cloud Platform quotas monitoring (alerting)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a question about quotas monitoring (I mean quotas in https://console.cloud.google.com -> IAM & admin -> Quotas).

I need configure alerting on cases, when the capacity of quota for any Service is less than 20%, for example. Has anybody done something like that? Maybe Google Cloud has some standard tools for that? If not, is it possible to do with python + gcloud module?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Compute Engine quotas, there is a Google Cloud standard tool to list them using [this API call](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/compute/compute/v1/compute.projects.get). Or find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota) the CLI command used to list them, in yaml format:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject
```

You can use a [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) to perform a regular scheduled task, calling the API and verifying that the `usage/limit<0.8` condition is met.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's doesn't receive all information about quotas. I've already tried it before... For example, I can't find out free CPU in output. But, anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: Check the CPUS_ALL_REGIONS field.